# Error while stopping Tomcat, using astyanax cassandra driver

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, cassandra, astyanax

I use astyanax cassandra driver on tomcat to access data from cassandra.
while stopping tomcat server; it is hung on threads started from astyanax library.
Has any one come across this issue?

[Stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/TSCJ0zY9)

```
appears to have started a thread named [SMA_ScoreReset] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak .
```

`appears to have started a thread named [pool-7-thread-35] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak`

I do have code which is to supposed to bring down the connection on shutdown

```
AstyanaxContext context = (AstyanaxContext)this.contextMap.get(ksName);
            if(context != null) {
                logger.info("shutdown context for keyspace " + ksName);
                ExecutorService asyncExecutor = context.getAstyanaxConfiguration().getAsyncExecutor();
                asyncExecutor.shutdown();

                try {
                    asyncExecutor.awaitTermination(10000L, TIMEUNIT);
                } catch (InterruptedException var6) {
                    ;
                }

                context.shutdown();`
```

Comment: can you include a stack trace? can use `jstack`

Comment: @ChrisLohfink : the stack trace has been attached as paste bin link http://pastebin.com/TSCJ0zY9

Comment: @ChrisLohfink : the threads with "YJPAgent" are the Yourkit profiler threads